# Is it possible to query JSON data from amazon Dynamodb using javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

I need help on amazon Dynamo. I am looking to special query in dynamodb

my JSON looks below

```
{
  blocknumber: '20',
  BusinessData: {
    BASE_UNIT: 'kg',
    FARMERID: 'FAINKABR0001',
    FARMLOCATION: 'Farm 3927',
    GAPINFO: {},
    PLANTINGDATE: '2020-11-02T18:30:00.000Z',
    PRODUCEQUANTITES: [
      {
        name: 'Priya',
        qty: 200
      }
    ],
    SELECTED_UNIT: {
      NAME: 'kg'
    }
  },
  chaincodeID: 'producechaincode',
  docType: 'Produce',
  PRID: 'PRFAINKABR0007',
  PRODUCE: 'Sweetcorn',
  STATUS: 'Approved',
  timestamp: '2020-12-06T13:03:08.857Z'
}
```

I would like to query all Data(Produce) where FARMERID is 'FAINKABR0001'.
I went through all of the examples but it seems that I can query only on hash key, sort key and using GSI.
Can we query it using Javascript SDK of AWS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Query` operation in DynamoDB finds items based on primary key values. You can query any table or secondary index (`GSI`) that has a composite primary key (a partition key and a sort key).

Now for your question, you have two options: 
**Option 1**

- Make `FARMERID` as your GSI

**Option 2**

- Use `Scan` method and filter the result

Now you will need to do cost evaluation based on your need. Each method has it's own pros and cons.

PFB some references:

[Scan-JS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.Scan)

[Query-DDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)

**Based on comment, one approach could be**

```js
var data = 
[
    {
  blocknumber: '20',
  BusinessData: {
    BASE_UNIT: 'kg',
    FARMERID: 'FAINKABR0001',
    FARMLOCATION: 'Farm 3927',
    GAPINFO: {},
    PLANTINGDATE: '2020-11-02T18:30:00.000Z',
    PRODUCEQUANTITES: [
      {
        name: 'Priya',
        qty: 200
      }
    ],
    SELECTED_UNIT: {
      NAME: 'kg'
    }
  },
  chaincodeID: 'producechaincode',
  docType: 'Produce',
  PRID: 'PRFAINKABR0007',
  PRODUCE: 'Sweetcorn',
  STATUS: 'Approved',
  timestamp: '2020-12-06T13:03:08.857Z'
},
{
  blocknumber: '20',
  BusinessData: {
    BASE_UNIT: 'kg',
    FARMERID: 'FAINKABR0002',
    FARMLOCATION: 'Farm 3927',
    GAPINFO: {},
    PLANTINGDATE: '2020-11-02T18:30:00.000Z',
    PRODUCEQUANTITES: [
      {
        name: 'Priya',
        qty: 200
      }
    ],
    SELECTED_UNIT: {
      NAME: 'kg'
    }
  },
  chaincodeID: 'producechaincode',
  docType: 'Produce',
  PRID: 'PRFAINKABR0007',
  PRODUCE: 'Sweetcorn',
  STATUS: 'Approved',
  timestamp: '2020-12-06T13:03:08.857Z'
},

{
  blocknumber: '20',
  BusinessData: {
    BASE_UNIT: 'kg',
    FARMERID: 'FAINKABR0001',
    FARMLOCATION: 'Farm 3927',
    GAPINFO: {},
    PLANTINGDATE: '2020-11-02T18:30:00.000Z',
    PRODUCEQUANTITES: [
      {
        name: 'Priya',
        qty: 200
      }
    ],
    SELECTED_UNIT: {
      NAME: 'kg'
    }
  },
  chaincodeID: 'producechaincode',
  docType: 'Produce',
  PRID: 'PRFAINKABR0007',
  PRODUCE: 'Sweetcorn',
  STATUS: 'Approved',
  timestamp: '2020-12-06T13:03:08.857Z'
}
];

function filterResponse(data, id) {
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].BusinessData.FARMERID === id ) {
      console.log(data[i]);
    }
  }
}

filterResponse(data, "FAINKABR0001");
```

Comment: Mark the answer accepted if it solves your problem. Thanks 

Comment: Thanks Atul for your answer I mentioned that we can do using GSI but we can use only 20 GSI per table so I would like to go option 2 but when I checked link you shared for option 2 it also not satisfied my question as its showing FilterExpression only primary  key as 'year' but I am looking something like into json structure as mention in question.

Comment: `FilterExpression` specifies a condition that returns only items that satisfy the condition. All other items are discarded.

Comment: FilterExpression need not be PK

Comment: DDB Scan basically gets all the data stored in dynamoDB, and it is upto you how you want to use it. You can even write your own filter method if you like

Comment: Yes I am trying to write javascript code for filter method however not getting any value do you have any idea how to achieve it?

Comment: Use simple `JSON` key-value in filter, there multiple way to do that and now your problem is not with DDB but about how to filter.

Comment: Updated the answer, with some code to work on and optimise

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Atul Kumar for Help I have also added my whole code my be in future somebody face same issue
Here FilterExpression as  `FilterExpression: "BusinessData.FARMERID = :farmeridvalue"`

Here we need to give FilterExpression value which attribute we want to query i.e `BusinessData.FARMERID` and give one name as I give `farmeridvalue` now you have set `ExpressionAttributeValues` as search value for me as `FAINKABR0001`

see whole scan code as below

```
var params = {
    TableName: "Your_tableName",
    FilterExpression: "BusinessData.FARMERID = :farmeridvalue",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":farmeridvalue" :"FAINKABR0001"

    }
};

docClient.scan(params, onScan);

function onScan(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        // print all the movies
        console.log("Scan succeeded.", data);
        data.Items.forEach(function(Block) {
           console.log( "result",
                Block.docType + ": ",
                Block.timestamp, "- rating:",  Block.BusinessData.FARMERID);
        });

        // continue scanning if we have more movies, because
        // scan can retrieve a maximum of 1MB of data
        if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
            console.log("Scanning for more...");
            params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
            docClient.scan(params, onScan);
        }
    }
}
```